# Laravel artisan issue with csrf protection and authentication

Tags: laravel, server, laravel-artisan

Can you tell me please, what is happening here? If I run on server which has been established by artisan serve command, I have a problem with csrf token control. If I compare session token and form token field, they are right(both are the same). But after form send it throws me an error - mishmash token exception. 
Another problem is with automatic logout, where few clicks after login I am suddenly logged out. Absolutely incorrectly and unexpectedly.

If I run without artisan server via localhost/laraapp/public/... it works well. Can you tell me what is wrong with artisan server?

Thanks.

Comment: " But after form send it throws me an error " : please post the code.
" few clicks after login I am suddenly logged out " : see lifetime var in config/session

Comment: That is ok 'lifetime' => 120,

Comment: Try using a different session driver than the `file` driver. It can sometimes have issues with lock race conditions if you're making rapid requests.

Comment: I don't want another driver.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache using
`php artisan cache:clear`
and clear the cache files.
At times they persist old data and they cause problems.
If you are using file as a session driver, try using cookie or database instead.
If you are already using cookies, delete the corresponding cookies in your browser.
And you have mentioned that your app is logging you out randomly!
Have you created any middleware which affects the session?
Default laravel app does nothing like that.

Comment: Still not working. I have changed driver to cookie, made cache:clear, cleared cache folder. Still the same problem.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 5.2 requires you to use web middleware to access session and coockies etc.